# struct node vs std::list< >

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, stdlist

While trying to understand linked lists I've come across this or similar ways to construct linked lists:

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    node *next;
}node;

node* init(int a[], int n){
    node *head, *p;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        node *nd = new node();
        nd->data = a[i];
        if(i==0){
            head = p = nd;
            continue;
        }
        p->next = nd;
        p = nd;
    }
    return head;
}
```

But why use this instead of std::list<..> ?

Comment: Why is this typedef named 'node' of a structure named 'node' too?

Comment: I vote to close this question since there's no 'correct' answer. I'd guess that implementing singly linked lists instead of using `std::list` is useful as an exercise, and to appreciate why certain algorithmic complexities on `std::list` (e.g. insertion being constant, lookup being linear) are the way they are. The `typedef struct node` part looks a lot like this was based on some C code.

Comment: In production code there is really no reason. It is often a learning exercise to learn how linked lists work under the hood.

Comment: It's a singly-linked list, so the direct counterpart is C++11 `std::forward_list`. `std::list` is a doubly-linked list.

Answer (score 2):

Because this way it works in C too.

This is useful when you are writing a library which can be used from both C and C++.

It might also be that the code was formerly C and then moved to C++ to use some C++ feature in other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged the question C++ and not C, the most sane answer to

> But why use this instead of std::list<..>

is that you wouldn't if you can use the standard library and its single-linked list class template `std::forward_list`. For example, some embedded environments might allow you to use C++ and most of its capabilities, but not all of the standard library.